# Multiple middlewares through router.params()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, router

In Node-Express, can the function `router.params()` accept multiple middlewares as parameters? I have the following set up:

```
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {console.log("checking auth"); next()}
const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {console.log("checking id"); next()}

router.params('id', checkAuth, checkID);
```

But only `checking auth` appears in the console.

In a Udemy course I'm taking in order to learn NodeJS the instructor said it would be possible but I'm not understating what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {console.log("checking auth"); next()}
const checkID= (req, res, next) => {console.log("checking id"); next()}

router.params('id', checkAuth, checkID);

Comment: name are different